# Input parameter instead of using raw_input to write python function

Tags: python, sqlite, input, parameters

we are writing a def. here is our logic:

> 1. input table's field name,
> 2. input parameter to the parentheses(parentheses is set for some commands who needs to input string  such as:
>
>    ```
>    interface fa(1)/(2)
>    ip address (3) (4))
>    ```
>
>    input parameter to the parentheses (if requested),then will select command from sqlite db.
>
>    ```
>    interface fa0/1
>    ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
>    ```
> 3. Finally output commands.

Recently, my partner requests me that I have not to use `input`. He told me that I should use `"input parameter"`. And I didn't understand him and he is not responding me about this question.

I have no idea now. What does it mean?

This is my and my partners python codes:

```
def get_input():
    a = input("function and params (comma separated):")
    b = input("device:")
    pattern = re.compile('\(.*?\)')

    output_commands = []

    params = a.split(',')

    function = params[0]

    print (params)

    counter = 1
    for result in readciscodevice(function,b):
        command = result[0]
        found_parentheses_list = re.findall(pattern, command)

        output_command = command



        for i, param_placeholder in enumerate(found_parentheses_list):

            param = params[counter]
            output_command = re.sub(pattern, param, output_command, count=1)
            counter +=1
        output_commands.append(output_command)

    return output_commands


# other program calls:

commands = get_input()

for command in commands:
    #do sth, print for example
    print(command)
```

Comment: Look up "function arguments".

Comment: he probably means your function must accept those values as parameters, so he can call it like `get_input(a,b)`

Comment: If you're working on a team project and you're unclear on what a team member is telling you, the person to talk to is that team member. This is a communications issue, not a coding issue.